# Tag not interpreted

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, handlebars.js

I have a problem with my script.

I **Insert** in my bdd my mails thanks to the Outlook API. To make an Insert I get the source code of my mail then insert it, so far no problem.

After that I make a **select** to display the mail in another page. My problem is that

> the source code is not interpreted

, it shows me all the tags, I don't understand why it doesn't read them.

my echo that displays my emails following the SELECT. My variable $result[body] displays the source code of the email... How do I force it to convert?

```html
 echo nl2br('<!DOCTYPE html>'.'<div class="emailBody">'.'<div class="list-group-item-heading premier">' . $result[from_mail] . '</div>' ."\n". '<div class="second">' . $result[recei] .'</div>' ."\n". '<div id="post1" class="trois azerty">' . '<p class="azerty bodypreview_1">' . $result[subject]. '</p>'."\n".'<div class="demasquer">' .'<p class="body_1">'.$result[body].'</p>'.")".'</div>'.'</div>'. '</div>');
```

Comment: Can you reduce your question to the relevant parts? Is the JS code neccessary if you have a problem with the database code?

Comment: Hi, yes, I can do that, I wanted to be as specific as possible. I'll reduce it.

Comment: Sorry, wscourge, I don't understand what you want me to do.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, what I meant was printing the `$result[body]` variable and pasting the result into your question:  `echo '<pre>'; print_r($result[body]); echo '</pre>';`

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to help myself thanks to the use of "html_entity_decode".
Now my tags are being interpreted.
 Correction:

```html
echo  html_entity_decode('<!DOCTYPE html>'  .'<div class="emailBody">'.'<div class="list-group-item-heading premier">' . $result[from_mail] . '</div>' ."\n". '<div class="second">' . $result[recei] .'</div>' ."\n". '<div id="post1" class="trois azerty">' . '<p class="azerty bodypreview_1">' . $result[subject]. '</p>'."\n". '<head>' .'</head>'.'<div class="demasquer">' .'<p class="body_1">'. $result[body] .'</p>'.'</div>'.'</div>'. '</div>');
```